# Can you obtain end gateway blocks in survival mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The end gateway block looked cool, so I want to decorate my house with it. However, is there a way to get it since I am playing hardcore? (without mods)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The player cannot legitimately obtain End gateway portal frames in Survival mode.

The only way that End gateway portal frames can exist in the world are in the form of gateway portals at the edges of the main End island that generate each time you kill the Ender dragon.

You cannot destroy or move End gateway portal frames with intentional MineCraft game mechanics, and you also can't collect End gateways, which means you won't be placing them down either.

Comment: oh, what a disappointment...

Comment: Although you can get it by turning on LAN, Cheats on, and `/setblock` a coordinate to an end gateway block.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible in survival.

You wouldn't want to do that since you would get teleported into the end if you walk into them.

You might want to look into resource packs, though.

Comment: So I can just make oak planks with the gateway texture and cover the floor with it?

Comment: @DREADLORDXD Yeah, I think it's possible, but might be somewhat difficult.